# easier way to find an integral?

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, contour-integration

Is there an easy way for : $$\int \frac{e^{\frac{1}{z}-2}}{z+2}dz$$ on$|z|=3$ ? thanks for any hint.

(I try it by series expansion , but someone told me there is an easy way to find it )

Comment: Just change variable to $\rho = \frac{1}{z-2}$. Look at my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1615293/59379) for a similar integral for an example. In certain sense, we can evaluate this integral by first deforming the contour to  a circle of infinite radius and then compute the residue of the pole at $\infty$.

Comment: I rolled back to the original version with the typo. Although you edited before the answer was posted, there was already invested considerable work in the answer at that point, so I think it's better to keep the original version of the question here. If the answer and/or the comment by achille hui aren't sufficient for you to solve your actual problem, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral is $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues at the poles inside $|z|=3$, i.e., at $z=-2$ and $z=0$.

At $z=-2$, we have a simple pole and the residue is $e^{-1/2-2}$.

At $z=0$, we have an essential singularity.  Here, we take the Laurent expansion of the integrand at $z=0$ and look for the coefficient of $z^{-1}$.  Note that

$$\frac1{2+z} = \frac12 \frac1{1+\frac{z}{2}} = \frac12 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k} z^k $$

Further,

$$e^{1/z} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac1{m! z^m} $$

Thus the residue is

$$\frac1{e^2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2^{k+1} (k+1)!} = -\frac1{e^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2^k k!} = \frac1{e^2} \left (1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\right )$$

Thus, the integral is

$$\oint_{|z|=3} dz \frac{e^{1/z-2}}{z+2} = i 2 \pi \left (\frac1{e^2}-\frac{1}{e^2 \sqrt{e}} + \frac1{e^2 \sqrt{e}} \right ) = \frac{i 2 \pi}{e^2}$$

Comment: thank you ! but I made some typo ...first .Now i correct it . can you me help me again $$e^\frac{1}{z-2}$$

Comment: $z=\pm 2$ two singularity in $|z|3$

Comment: @Khosrotash: Please do me and everyone else a favor.  Put back the original problem and create a new question with your new function.  I don't have an infinite amount of time to spend working on these and I spent a lot of time on this one - not my problem that you made a mistake.

Comment: @Khosrotash: Also, see if you can solve the current problem given how I solved the previous one.

Comment: You are right ...thank you again..thank you so much