# A complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, laurent-series

Let $C$ is positive oriented $|z|=1/2$ circle.

Calculate $\int_C \frac{e^{1/z^2}}{z-1}dz$

I think I can solve it via using residue. The only singular point is $0$ in there. Should I write Laurent series of $e^{1/z^2}$ in $1<|z-1|< \infty $ neighborhood?

Last, if the circle were $|z|=1$ what should I do in that situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Minor variant of [Calculating $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{e^{1/z^2}}{1-z}dz$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615241/calculating-int-z-2-frace1-z21-zdz)

Comment: Yeah, just use Residue theorem. About $|z| = 1$, the function isn't defined at $z = 1$. How would you want to integrate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$$\frac{e^{\frac1{z^2}}}{1-z}=\left(1+\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{2!z^4}+\frac1{3!z^6}+\cdots\right)(1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots)\tag1$$and since the residue of $\frac{e^{\frac1{z^2}}}{1-z}$ at $0$ is the coefficient of $\frac1z$ that you get multiplying the series from $(1)$, then that residue is equal to$$1+\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\cdots=e-1.$$Therefore, your integral is equal to $2\pi i(e-1)$.

Comment: The singular point here is $z= 0 $, not $z = 1$

Comment: Could you please write it with more detail? (with series) In addition is the domain I wrote for series true?

Comment: @user519955 [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615241/calculating-int-z-2-frace1-z21-zdz) contains sufficient detail IMO

Comment: @YuiToCheng I hope to find an answer with series for my first question especially and they concerned with singularity at $1$ at most and someone used product of two series but one of those series is Laurent and the other one is Taylor in that domain. How can we product them?

Comment: @Jakobian Quite true. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @user519955 I've edited my answer, which was wrong. What do you think now?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos you have written so clear. I wrote almost everything same with yours but I couldn’t see that series converges to $e-1$. Thank a lot

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The area of convergence for $e^\frac{1}{z^2}$ is always $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, which is good, beacuse you want it to be convergent in the vincinity of $0$.

You have $$e^\frac{1}{z^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}z^{-2n}$$
and in the vincinity of $z=0$:
$$ \frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty z^m$$
so
\begin{align} \frac{e^\frac{1}{z^2}}{1-z} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}z^{m-2n} = \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=-2n}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}z^{k} = \\
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\sum_{n\ge\max\{0,-\frac{k}{2}\}}  \frac{1}{n!}z^{k} = \\
\end{align}
Therefore the residdum at $0$, the coefficient at $z^{-1}$ is equal to
$$ a_{-1} = \sum_{n\ge\max\{0,\frac{1}{2}\}}  \frac{1}{n!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{n!} = e-1$$

If the circle were to be $|z|>1$ you need to specify how you surround the singularity at $z=1$, or whether you want to calculate the principal value of the integral.

For the circle $|z|=R>1$ you'd need to include the residuum for $z=1$, or expand function $\frac{1}{1-z}$ in the region $|z|>1$ ($\frac{1}{1-z} = -\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^{-k}$) and find the coefficient $a_{-1}$ in subsequently obtained series for $\frac{e^{1/z^2}}{1-z}$.